# How to retrieve date and time from a tweepy status object?

Tags: datetime, tweepy

Suppose I do

```
tweets = api.home_timeline()
```

It returns a list of 20 recent tweepy status objects that is posted on my timeline.And if I do

```
for tweet in tweets:
    print tweet.text
```

It prints 20 messages.Is it possible to retrieve the time the status was posted? What other attributes does the status object have? Help needed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
tweet = tweets[0]
print tweet.created_at
```

Output will be a datetime object. E.g.:

```
(Pdb) tweet.created_at
datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 3, 20, 9, 24)
```

For all attributes, see the [Twitter API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/home_timeline). [Tweepy docs](http://packages.python.org/tweepy/html/index.html) will also interest you.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? status.created_at seems to be the same string as given by the twitter api and not a datetime.

Comment: @mbarkhau I was working directly in the Python debugger when I posted this. Haven't played with Tweepy much lately. If it is different, the library must have been updated since the version I was using.

Comment: it turns out somebody had monkeypatched tweepy because it wasn't parsing the dates properly and so I was getting the raw strings.

Comment: Hi. How do I get the list of all the attributes available? Pycharm doesn't seem to suggest any/all of them and the twitter api link seems to be broken.